# How to identify in which region new point will lie using Sklearn Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a sample code for the Sklearn taken from the website. I am trying to learn how to classify points using Sklearn(Scikit-Learn). Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons, make_circles, make_classification
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay

names = [
    "Nearest Neighbors",
]

classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(3),
]

X, y = make_classification(
    n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2, random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1
)
rng = np.random.RandomState(2)
X += 2 * rng.uniform(size=X.shape)
linearly_separable = (X, y)

datasets = [
    linearly_separable,
]

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(27, 9))
i = 1
# iterate over datasets
for ds_cnt, ds in enumerate(datasets):
    # preprocess dataset, split into training and test part
    X, y = ds
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=42
    )

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 0.5, X[:, 0].max() + 0.5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 0.5, X[:, 1].max() + 0.5

    # just plot the dataset first
    cm = plt.cm.RdBu
    cm_bright = ListedColormap(["#FF0000", "#0000FF"])
    ax = plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(classifiers) + 1, i)
    if ds_cnt == 0:
        ax.set_title("Input data")
    # Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright, edgecolors="k")
    # Plot the testing points
    ax.scatter(
        X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm_bright, alpha=0.6, edgecolors="k"
    )
    ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
    ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    i += 1

    # iterate over classifiers
    for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
        ax = plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(classifiers) + 1, i)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
        All_Value_Response = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
            clf, X, cmap=cm, alpha=0.8, ax=ax, eps=0.5
        )

        # Plot the training points
        ax.scatter(
            X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright, edgecolors="k"
        )
        # Plot the testing points
        ax.scatter(
            X_test[:, 0],
            X_test[:, 1],
            c=y_test,
            cmap=cm_bright,
            edgecolors="k",
            alpha=0.6,
        )

        ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
        ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
        ax.set_xticks(())
        ax.set_yticks(())
        if ds_cnt == 0:
            ax.set_title(name)
        ax.text(
            x_max - 0.3,
            y_min + 0.3,
            ("%.2f" % score).lstrip("0"),
            size=15,
            horizontalalignment="right",
        )
        i += 1

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output Image]

Now as one can see the areas formed are not regular shapes, so it is becoming a little difficult to understand how to know if a new point arrives and will lie in which region. I managed to capture the data of the regions (`All_Value_Response` variable stores that information) but it seems not helpful to me.

So I want to know if I want to know in which region does the point `(1,3)` lies then how I can deduce it through code. I can do it by seeing on the graph but how to make it work using the code?

Please help me find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons, make_circles, make_classification
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay

names = [
    "Nearest Neighbors",
]

classifiers = [
    KNeighborsClassifier(3),
]

X, y = make_classification(
    n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=2, random_state=1, n_clusters_per_class=1
)
rng = np.random.RandomState(2)
X += 2 * rng.uniform(size=X.shape)
linearly_separable = (X, y)

datasets = [
    linearly_separable,
]

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(27, 9))
i = 1
# iterate over datasets
for ds_cnt, ds in enumerate(datasets):
    # preprocess dataset, split into training and test part
    X, y = ds
    X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=42
    )

    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 0.5, X[:, 0].max() + 0.5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 0.5, X[:, 1].max() + 0.5

    # just plot the dataset first
    cm = plt.cm.RdBu
    cm_bright = ListedColormap(["#FF0000", "#0000FF"])
    ax = plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(classifiers) + 1, i)
    if ds_cnt == 0:
        ax.set_title("Input data")
    # Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright, edgecolors="k")
    # Plot the testing points
    ax.scatter(
        X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm_bright, alpha=0.6, edgecolors="k"
    )
    ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
    ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    i += 1

    # iterate over classifiers
    for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
        ax = plt.subplot(len(datasets), len(classifiers) + 1, i)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
        All_Value_Response = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
            clf, X, cmap=cm, alpha=0.8, ax=ax, eps=0.5
        )

        # Plot the training points
        ax.scatter(
            X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright, edgecolors="k"
        )
        # Plot the testing points
        ax.scatter(
            X_test[:, 0],
            X_test[:, 1],
            c=y_test,
            cmap=cm_bright,
            edgecolors="k",
            alpha=0.6,
        )
        
        X1 = All_Value_Response.xx0.ravel()
        Y1 = All_Value_Response.xx1.ravel()
        Color = All_Value_Response.response.ravel()
        
        Outputs = []
        
        for X2, Y2 in X:
            XD = X2 - X1
            YD = Y2 - Y1
            Distance = (XD * XD) + (YD * YD)
            Color_Gradient = Color[Distance.argmin()]
            Outputs.append(Color_Gradient)
        
        print(Outputs)
        ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
        ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
        ax.set_xticks(())
        ax.set_yticks(())
        if ds_cnt == 0:
            ax.set_title(name)
        ax.text(
            x_max - 0.3,
            y_min + 0.3,
            ("%.2f" % score).lstrip("0"),
            size=15,
            horizontalalignment="right",
        )
        i += 1

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have found a reference in of the question that you have asked : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74613354/4948889

The output of the above code is something like the below:
[image: output of the code]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can see other values other than `0` or `1` in the array that you show printed. I will check it and try it out. I think you got what I was expecting.

Comment: Cool this is exact what I was looking for. It helped. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have `X_train` and `X_test`. These are both lists containing tuples. The values in the tuples (a, b) have some range, like 0 -> 1. In your graphs, these are the x and y coordinates of your dots.

You also have `y_train` and `y_test`. These are the known classifications of all the tuples in `X_train` and `X_test`. These values can be either 0 or 1, and none in between. If a dot in your graph is in the blue region, that means that the predicted value of that dot (a, b) is 0. If the dot is in the red region, this means the predicted value is 1.

```py
# if X_train is this
X_train = [(0.0, 0.0), (0.1, 0.9), (0.9, 0.0), (1, 0.9)]

# then y_train has to be this, for you chart
y_train = [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

If you then train a classifier on this (but normally more data), then you can ask it any point (a, b) and it will tell you 0 or 1 (aka blue or red).

So for example I predict for a point (a, b) that it has not seen in X_train (aka something that is in X_test):

```py
result = clf.predict([(0.2, 0.2)])
```

`result` then equals: `[0]`. This is because looking at your graph, assuming x-axis and y-axis range 0 -> 1. The tuple (0.2, 0,2) falls in the blue region.

It knows this because it has learned the blue red classification you see in your graph from `X_train` and `X_test`. So when it gets new tuples it sees on which region that dot falls and classifies it as 0 or 1, region blue or region red.

To summarize. The colored regions show what value will be predicted for any given tuple (a, b). The dot positions (in the scatter) are given by the values (a, b) in the tuple. a and b for the tuple are in range between 0->1. The color is not a range, but a classification 0 or 1.

Hopefully it helps, good luck!

Comment: Okay you mean I should try predicting one by one the value and it will give me the region. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If that is what you mean then no it is not the answer I was expecting. I got the Y values using it and not the region values.

Comment: The input to your classifier is an (x, y) coordinate right? And is the output of the classifier is one of 4 classification?

Comment: It is important to differentiate the Y we are talking about. I believe the Y you talk about it the classification, not the y in an (x, y) coordinate.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the Y of classification. You know when I am using `predict()` it is giving me 0, or 1 as output but as you see in the figure there are 4 region and there has to me 4 values to differentiate the region.

Comment: And please check I have the question about in which region the point will lie and not what will be the output of the classifier.

Comment: Your regions indicate probability bounds of the classification, due to these parameters: `All_Value_Response = DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
            clf, X, cmap=cm, alpha=0.8, ax=ax, eps=0.5
 )`

you can use clf.predict_proba(...) to get closer to the region value.

Comment: Please can you add it in the answer because without that it wont be a helpful answer and I cannot accept it.

Comment: I have extended the answer, with the information from the comment.

Comment: Thank you for your response but still not the answer I am expectng.

Comment: If your clf.predict() is 0 it's in the blue region else the red region. Or vise versa. You can label to zones for more clarity.

Comment: Yes you are correct but as you see the inputs when plotted are not having 0 or 1 value. Then are also have certain values between 0 or 1. So now you could see it is not that simple.

Comment: You are looking at it wrong, you are not plotting the Y aka the 0 or 1 values. But you are only plotting X_train and X_test. The location of the points in your graph is based on the input the of the classifier not the output (aka 0 or 1). The can be seen as region colors. 0 means the point is blue, 1 means it's not in blue.

Comment: You input values have a range, those are the locations of the dots in your graph. Your output values do not. They are 0 or 1. Aka Blue or Red. Which u see as the regions in the graph.  You say you see that the values have a range. I am telling you the input value have a range. Not the output. The regions are the output. Blue or red, 1 or 0. That is not a range.

Comment: @JafferWilson I updated my entire answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Well we can definitely determine which region the new point will lie in, but before we do that I want to call attention to something you're doing in your code that is going to come back to bite you.

This line right here `X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)` will come back to smack you harder than you know.

Remember, the point of doing a StandardScaler is to standardize the data (0 mean, unit variance). Also remember that what you do on your training set you must do on your test set. The caveat here is the operations you perform on your test set will be **learned** from your training set. I'll give a condensed form of your code to help illustrate this.

```py
X, y = datasets[0]

# Save an instance of the standard scaler so we can apply it to unknown values later
standard_scalar = StandardScaler()
standard_scalar.fit(X)  # Fit the "training data"

X = standard_scalar.transform(X)  # Transform the data

# You ended up with a good score because the transformation in your data was applied to the entire dataset, "X". But normally you'd transform the X_test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=42)

# Train the classifier
clf =  KNeighborsClassifier(3)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)  # 0.925. Good score but let's see what happens next

# This is where things will go wrong in your code.
# Instead, make sure you transform the test point your want to calculate
>>> clf.predict([[1,3]])
array([0])

>>> clf.predict(standard_scalar.transform([[1,3]]))
array([1])
```

So even though you can use `predict` in both cases, you need to make sure to apply the transformation to the data point that you're inputting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have a small query. What if I am using the transformed standardized `X` value directly from the sample set? I have tried using the data of the `X` values from the sample and using predict I am getting only `0` or `1` as output. But as you can see that the regions are not just `0` and `1`. Now please let me know how predict will return the values other than 0 and 1 which is not at all possible. So please tell me how I can have the region values either by comparing the values of the region with the input or there is something else we can do.

Comment: The problem is `predict` function does not yield the output what I am looking for. If it gives me what I want then there is no point in placing this question. I have tried it already and when I did not get the answer I have placed the question here and have waited for days and since there was no one to answer I have to forcefully  place a bounty so someone get attention and can give me the answer I desire. But I am getting all I know already or can get it just by Googling it.